# What does the const specifier do, before a pointer to object?

Tags: objective-c, constants, cllocation

If I have a C-string like this:

```
const char* str= "hello";
```

I know well that I can't change any character of the string because the pointer is const.
But if I have this:

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

I can still mutate the object state using it's methods.
If the pointer is to a NSMutableString, I'm still able to mutate it.
Then what does the const stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that method declaration, `location` is a pointer to a constant `CLLocation`.  But when you send a message to the `location` object, the `const`-ness is not preserved; the method that handles the message sees `self` as a non-`const` object.  (Note that this is different than C++, which supports `const` member functions where `this` is a pointer to a constant object.)

So the `const` in that declaration is not particularly useful.  Perhaps it was written by someone used to the C++ way of doing things.

When you do see `const` attached to an object pointer in Objective-C, it is usually like this:

```
extern NSString * const SomeConstantString;
```

This declares `SomeConstantString` as a constant pointer to some non-constant object (in this case, an `NSString`).  The pointer itself is constant, so your program can't change `SomeConstantString` to point to some other `NSString` object.

Answer (score 1):

Mind the difference:

```
// constant pointer
char * const str = "";

// pointer to constant (two equivalent ways)
const char * str = "";
char const * str = "";
```

The keyword const applies applies to whatever is immediately to its left. If there is nothing to its left, it applies to whatever is immediately to its right.

In Objective-C all method parameters are always passed by value. This includes primitives, structs, unions, and pointers, and any other made up type.

Note that you can't have variables of type object. A expression like `NSObject o;` produces a compiler error with message "Interface type cannot be statically allocated".

The only way to pass an object is passing a pointer. The pointer is passed as value, but lets the code inside the method reference the object and change it. So in a way, it is *as if* you are passing the object by reference (in reality you are passing the pointer by value).

When compiling an Objective-C program, the methods are turned into C functions, and each "message send" (aka "method call", though it isn't exactly the same) is ran using the runtime function `objc_sendMsg`. This function doesn't know or care if you qualified the object with `const` or not. If you want an immutable object, you have to code that immutability inside the object. Example:

```
// const qualifying an object is ignored whether in variables or method arguments:
const NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];   // const is ignored
-(void)someMethod:(const NSMutableArray *)array { ... // const is ignored

// calling the methods that mutate the object works fine
[array removeAllObjects];
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know well that I can't change any character of the string because
>   the pointer is const.

No, the pointer is mutable. The characters it points to are const.

> I can still mutate the object state using it's methods.

There is no const-correctness for Objective-C objects like there is in C++. The compiler does not care which messages (mutating or not) you send to a const object. So there's no sense in declaring a pointer to a const object. The cited framework method is an anomaly, probably an oversight.